# Configure Spring.Web.Services.WebServiceProxyFactory for SOAP MTOM

Tags: soap, proxy, spring.net, mtom

I create proxy object for WCF servise with Spring.NEt frwm -  Spring.Web.Services.WebServiceProxyFactory.

**WCF service use SOAP MTOM.** Configuration is here:

```
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding    name="MTOM_BINDING" 
                maxReceivedMessageSize="10000000000" 
                receiveTimeout="00:10:00" 
                sendTimeout="00:10:00" 
                maxBufferSize="10000000000" 
                maxBufferPoolSize="524288" 
                bypassProxyOnLocal="true" 
                messageEncoding="Mtom">

      <readerQuotas 
                  maxArrayLength="10000000000" 
                  maxBytesPerRead="10000000000"
                  maxDepth="10000000000" 
                  maxNameTableCharCount="10000000000" 
                  maxStringContentLength="10000000000"/>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>

  <service      name="TestService" 
                behaviorConfiguration="DefaultBehavior">
    <endpoint   address="" 
                binding="basicHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="MTOM_BINDING" 
                contract="TestService.ITestService" 
                bindingNamespace="http://test.com/TEST" 
                behaviorConfiguration="SimpleWSDLBehavior"/>
    <endpoint 
                contract="IMetadataExchange" 
                binding="mexHttpBinding" 
                address="mex"/>
  </service>
```

Confuguration for Spring.Web.Services.WebServiceProxyFactory proxy object:

```
  <object id="testProxy"
          type="Spring.Web.Services.WebServiceProxyFactory, Spring.Services">
    <property name="ServiceUri" value="http://localhost/TestService.svc?wsdl"/>

    <property name="ServiceInterface" value="TestService.ITestService, TestService"/>

    <property name="ProductTemplate">
      <object>
        <property name="Timeout" value="2147483646" />
      </object>
    </property>
  </object>
```

I could’t find how can I specify for Spring.Web.Services.WebServiceProxyFactory that WCF service use not SOAP but SOAP MTOM.

Because this configuration of Spring.Web.Services.WebServiceProxyFactory  except SOAP mesage which has data serialized to text not binnary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WebServiceProxyFactory is for .asmx Web service.

For WCF support, see:
http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/wcf.html